# Counting restricted partitions

Tags: combinatorics, dynamic-programming, efficiency

Given positive intgers $N$ and $S$ i need to count in how many ways $N$ can be decomposed as sum of $S$ positive integers not greater than $\frac{N}{2}$:
$$ N = x_1 + \dots + x_S, ~~~~ 0 \leq x_i \leq \frac{N}{2} $$

Two partitions are considered distinct if any of the summands has distinct values in them. For example, if $N = 4$ and $S = 3$ then there are 6 possible partitions:
$$(1, 1, 2), (1, 2, 1), (2, 1, 1), (2, 2, 0), (2, 0, 2), (0, 2, 2)$$

I've derived a dynamic programming solution. Let $d_{ns}$ be the number of above defined partitions of number $n$ with $s$ summands (each not greater than $\frac{N}{2}$). Then
$$ d_{0s} = 1, ~~~ s \geq 0 $$
$$ d_{n0} = 0, ~~~ n > 0 $$
$$ d_{ns} = \sum_{k = 0}^{\max \left(n, \frac{N}{2} \right)}d_{n-k,s-1}, ~~~ sn > 0 $$

It works fine but i consider this approach to be too slow from algorithmic point of view. It requires roughly $O(N^2 S)$ operations.

So here's my question. Can this computation be done faster? Perhaps via some other recurrence or some smarter way to fill the dynamic programming table for recurrence described above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, let us note that the number of ways to write $N$ as a sum of $S$ non-negative integers is exactly $\binom{N+S-1}{N}$. Indeed, the partition $N=x_1+\cdots+x_S$ corresponds to the string $\ast^{x_1}|\ast^{x_2}|\cdots|\ast^{x_S}$ (where $\ast^x$ means $x$ many stars), which contains $N$ stars and $S-1$ bars, and conversely any such string corresponds to a partition.

In your case you have the additional constraint that all $x_i$s are at most $N/2$. Note that at most one $x_i$ can be more than $N/2$. If $x_i > N/2$, then the number of ways to fill the rest of the $x_j$s is exactly $\binom{N-x_i+S-2}{S-1}$. Therefore the number of ways to write $N$ as a sum of $S$ non-negative integers which are at most $N/2$ is
$$
\binom{N+S-1}{S-1} - S\sum_{x=\left\lceil \frac{N+1}{2} \right\rceil}^N \binom{N-x+S-2}{S-2} =
\binom{N+S-1}{S-1} - S\sum_{y=0}^{\left\lfloor \frac{N-1}{2} \right\rfloor} \binom{y+S-2}{S-2} =
\binom{N+S-1}{S-1} - S \binom{\left\lfloor \frac{N-1}{2} \right\rfloor+S-1}{S-1}.
$$
You can calculate this closed form using $O(S)$ arithmetic operations.